# How to change the default option choose one to user defined one like select country?

Tags: java, dropdown, wicket

Am trying to change the default drown down choice from choose one to select country. Is there a way to put custom value
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the [null](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/9e0e4249f6cbf4bc706547f217cd3b1ea3ba9458/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/Application.properties#L50) resource key.

In MyApplication.properties:

```
null=Select country
```

For more information consult with the [user guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/9.x/single.html#_internationalization_with_wicket).